# HDD Failure? Seagate 320GB

Tags: crash, hard-drive-failure, read-write

I have a Seagate Barracuda ST3320820SCE 320GB HDD 7200RPM Brand new from a trusted seller on eBay (i know, but it’s new)

Worked fine then today I got 2 crashes causing windows to shut down.

And Crystal Disk Info shows:

[image]

I use it as my User’s Folder, Steam, World of Warcraft, VMBox, and Video Storage. and I symlink my Temp, World At War Map to it

As you see it has 380 Hours of on time and one error. That picture shows all the attributes incase i dont understand any of it.

Since I un-linked the Temp folder and put it back on my SSD, I havnt gotten any crashes but that would be cause it just fails to read/write but wont crash cause its not handling important windows files.

- **Main Disk:** SSD (works just fine) Games and others: (Seagate failing)
- **Ubuntu:** WDC black (works fine) Backup usb hdd: (works fine)

I have a 1 year warranty so I might be able to get it replaced cause its only been a few months, but I dont have the original packaging or RMA paper. So maybe not?

Comment: If it has 380 hours that's of your use or it came that way?

Comment: I haven't used 300 hours, maybe around 100-150, so it may have been used a little bit but 300 hours is not much... my old NAS hdd has 24,000 Hours and still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk is stuffed - If the S.M.A.R.T health status is "Bad" [the manufacturer thinks the disk should be replaced](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/184619en), ie Failed SMART tests = needs to be replaced (free if under warranty).

Unfortunately a check of the [Seagate Warranty site](http://www.seagate.com/support/warranty-and-replacements/) indicates your disk is out of warranty - no surprise really as a 320 gig hard drive would be pretty old.

I would approach the seller asking them for a replacement/refund - if they provided you a 1 year warranty, they are really obliged to provide it if the SMART results come back negative, regardless of whether you kept the packaging.  Further, an RMA is not something you get with the drive, its something you get when you initiate a return process - and there is no special paper or form required - indeed it does not even have any legal weight, its simply a procedure implemented by vendors to track a returns process.

Comment: Yea it came from a HDD seller on ebay, they sell a lot of hdd's and provided a 1 year warranty. so hopefully they can replace or refund me